# WordPress meta query relation is not working?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Please have a look at my code.

```
$todayDate = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s'));
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(  
  'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '==',          
    ),
    array(
       'key' => 'expiration_date',
       'value' => $todayDate,
       'compare' => '>',          
    ),      
)       
);
```

When i run query its return that posts which have not featured_post = 1, What's wrong here?? I want to sort all posts which have featured_post =1 and and expiration_date is bigger then today?
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you replace this `'compare' => '=='` and try this please `'compare' => '='`

Comment: Same Problem, Its return same result which have not featured_post = 1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single `=` which will consider as correct operator in `featured_post` array, below is an example

```
array(
    'key' => 'featured_post',
    'value' => '1',
    'compare' => '=',          
 )
```

Comment: @MrShabir can you try `'value' => 1,` please? Add `1` as `integer` I hope it will work. Just remove single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Please check first for featured posts

```
$todayDate = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s'));
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(  
  'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => 'featured_post',
        'value' => '1',
        'compare' => '==',          
    ))
);
```

Comment: Okay, Please check in your code (functions.php) once if any "pre_get_posts" action is applied or not. if it's applied then can you disable/ comment it and check your code once ?

Comment: Thanks @Gunjan Patel, But i am not using pre_get_posts.